# Lost in two jDateChoosers date spans

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm lost,  trying to take dates from two `jDateChoosers` then query derby database table "TEST5" column "DATEDATE" to list all records between these two dates out to my jTable.

```
 private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/test5";
    String user = "APP";
    String pass = "APP";

        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url ,user, pass);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainDisplay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }




        java.sql.Date dateStart = new java.sql.Date(jDateChooser2.getDate().getTime()); 
        java.sql.Date dateEnd = new java.sql.Date(jDateChooser3.getDate().getTime());   


       try (PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT DateDate FROM TEST5 WHERE DateDate between ? AND ?" ); 
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery()) {
                    st.setDate(1, dateStart);//set start date
                    st.setDate(2, dateEnd);//set end date
                    MainDisplay.jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));


                    rs.close();
                    st.close();
                    con.close();


        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainDisplay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

This is my latest revision ( sorry, not sure where to post reply's yet)

Comment: The error says the column datestart is not in the table. So go to mysql and describe the table and check if the column is there and also try to execute the sql first in mysql before trying in the program.

Comment: your issue seems more about table related as Isiva mentioned than date chooser. but just in case add log statements to see if date vales are selected properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't set any value to `dateStart >= ? AND dateEnd <= ?` you have to use:

```
try (PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT DateDate FROM TEST5 WHERE dateStart >= ? AND dateEnd <= ?");) {
    st.setDate(1, dateStart);//set start date
    st.setDate(2, dateEnd);//set end date
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery()
    MainDisplay.jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

Also, make sure that you set the correct name of your columns, `DateDate, dateStart, dateEnd`

---

**Edit**

If i understand, in your case your table has just one date and you want to get all the dates `<= startDate` and `>= endDate` this date, in this case you can use :

```
SELECT DateDate FROM TEST5 WHERE DateDate >= ? AND DateDate <= ?
```

This similaire to this `between` :

```
SELECT DateDate FROM TEST5 WHERE DateDate between ? AND ?
```

Comment: ..... The Derby database is already storing  all my dates constantly in Table "TEST5" column "DateDate"  ..... lets say I now have 1K date records in column "DateDate" (ie: 2017 04 02)  I wish to call up to my jTable all record columns between these two sselected dates I selected with my jDate Choosers.  (I don't want to "st..setDates")

Comment: then how your query know your dates if you don't want to use `setDate` @Rick19007 ?

Comment: Do I understand you in that I must now add two new columns "dateStart" and DateEnd" to my existing table "TEST5" ????  .... to conduct a date span search of my records?  Thats how this all works?

Comment: @Rick19007 if you have only one date you can use between i will edit my answer so you can understand more ok

Comment: "java.sql.SQLException: At least one parameter to the current statement is uninitialized".   I get this error in both versions of your edited answ.er when I try to run it.  :  (

Comment: what did you try, show me your code please @Rick19007

Comment: stmt.setDate(7,sqlDate); // Here is my DateDate column time going "INTO" database <----------------- < HERE!  (if that matters at all) .... from another class grabbing and then storing the dates automatically.

Comment: "java.sql.SQLException: At least one parameter to the current statement is uninitialized". I get this error in both versions of your edited answ.er when I try to run it. : (

Comment: @Rick19007 because you execute your query before you set the values to your Statement, so you have to use my solution exactly